# Pagination options using xml data instead of database?

Tags: pagination, xml

Working on a custom plugin.  I have an XML file containing over 500 items I need to make available for posting at the client's discretion. The client wants to share this plugin among a small group of peers, with no access to a central database, hence the XML file. We've done something similar in the past using data stored in a MySQL table and WP_List_Table for display and pagination, but I'm unsure about how to proceed using XML.

I'd prefer we create all posts as drafts that they can publish as desired, but for reasons I don't quite comprehend, that's not an option.

Basically, they want to see a list of all available items where they can simply click to publish individually or check multiple items and publish in bulk.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Question is more about how to traverse xml using php and less about wordpress..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No central database?  Talk about not being able to see the forest for the trees. As long as the XML document is included with the plugin, I can just create a custom table and proceed as we have in the past.  I do understand WP_List_Table is marked private, but I don't see anything wrong using it for a private plugin that will never make it to the repo.